# Docker- PHP application image for deployment not working locally

Tags: php, docker, symfony, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to test my php server to run the application before deploying it on AWS (first time) Doesn't work for me locally with my docker configuration.

I use:

```
docker build -f docker-configs/php/Dockerfile -t php-service .

docker run -p 9000:9000  php-service
```

and there is no response from **localhost:9000**

> Logs show:
>
> [23-Aug-2023 08:37:53] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
>
> [23-Aug-2023 08:37:53] NOTICE: ready to handle connections

but can't connect.

My `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    unzip \
    libicu-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    wget \
    && apt-get install -y \
    librabbitmq-dev \
    libssh-dev \
    sqlite3 \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
    bcmath \
    sockets \
    pdo pdo_mysql pdo_sqlite \
    && pecl install amqp \
    && docker-php-ext-enable amqp

# Installing Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer && composer --version

RUN apt-get -y install cron default-mysql-client

WORKDIR /app

# Copy application files into the container
COPY . /app

# Expose port 9000 for the PHP-FPM server
EXPOSE 9000

# The startup command to run PHP-FPM
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Also, I found out that - PHP-FPM doesn't handle HTTP requests directly; it needs a web server like Nginx or Apache to translate HTTP requests into FastCGI requests that PHP-FPM can handle.

So I guess need image which I can access with HTTP request?

Also my `docker-compose.yaml` file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - "./docker-configs/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
      - ".:/app:cached"
  php:
    build:
      context: ./docker-configs/php
    volumes:
      - "./docker-configs/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini"
      - ".:/app:cached"
    environment:
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=Docker"

  database:
    image: nouchka/sqlite3:latest
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./sqlite-data:/var/lib/sqlite
```

Can someone please help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. *FPM* images don't have web servers in it, you need an external web server (either [nginx](https://www.nginx.org) or [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org)) to "accept" requests from the outside and "forward" them to the application.

Comment: Since you intend to deploy it on [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com), you probably need a [load balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing) whose job will be to accept incoming requests and send out responses. Then you need to deploy your app via [container service](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs) where the load balancer will forward all the incoming requests.